# $unwind, produce complement of results in addition to target of "path"

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection called scorerecords that has documents that look like:

```
{status: 'in progress', teams: {count: 2, team: [ {name: "team 1", score: 100}, {name: "team 2", score: 95}]}}
```

I would like to return a unique record for each element in the "teams.team" array (as can be done with $unwind), but have it also return the opposite team record (the "opponent"). Example:

```
{status: 'in progress', teams: {count: 2, team: {name: "team 1", score: 100}, opponent: {name: "team 2", score: 95}}}
{status: 'in progress', teams: {count: 2, team: {name: "team 2", score: 95}, opponent: {name: "team 1", score: 100}}}
```

This way, I would have 1 record per team (instead of 1 per matchup), and could calculate the number of times a team won or lost (e.g. by using a $project statement to define a "winner:true/false" field or something similar).

Is there any way to do that with some combination of $aggregate functions like $project/$unwind?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution:

```
db.scorerecords.aggregate([{$addFields: {"teams.team": {$map: {input: "$teams.team", as: "tm", in: {"name": "$$tm.name", "score":"$$tm.score", "idx": {$indexOfArray: ["$teams.team", "$$tm"]} }}}}},{$addFields: {"teams.team": {$map: {input: "$teams.team", as: "tm", in: {"name": "$$tm.name", "score": "$$tm.score", "opp": {$arrayElemAt: ["$teams.team", {$subtract: [1, "$$tm.idx"]}]}} }}}}, {$unwind: "$teams.team"} ])
```

It seems like there might have been a more convenient/efficient method, but this way seems to return the desired result.

Steps: 
1) Add a field that identifies the "index" of the current item in the array with a $map call. 
2) Using another $map call, add an "opp" field, assuming the opp is the (1-idx)th entry in the array (see caution below). 
3) Use $unwind to flatten, creating 2x the original recordset with the complementary records included.

Caution on step #2: 
(This assumes that every scorerecord will have <=2 teams. If there is only 1, the "opp" field will not be populated, which is desirable. It will have unexpected results if there are more than 2 teams in the "teams.team" array. (e.g. for every team beyond the 2nd, it will return the last element in the array as the "opp").